# Ajax 500 error in jquery.min - send/ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I am using Ajax to send a post request to my Flask application and get some data back. However, I keep getting a 500 error where there seems to be an issue with jquery.min not having the ajax methods.

This works on localhost, however when I deploy my application to google cloud I get the 500 error whenever I call this function. I have tried multiple version of jquery.min that I know accept ajax.

As it works on local host I am clueless and been stuck here for hours. 
My other Flask endpoints hit fine, so it is definitely in the ajax request.

Can anyone offer any solutions?

JS

```
<script>
    function recommendation(){
        data = sessionStorage.getItem("imgAlt")
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/predict/",
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data){
                        var recImages = data.imageList[0]
                        var recImages2 = data.imageList[1]
                        var recImages3 = data.imageList[2]

                        sessionStorage.setItem("listOfImages1", recImages);
                        sessionStorage.setItem("listOfImages2", recImages2);
                        sessionStorage.setItem("listOfImages3", recImages3);

                    }
            });
}
</script>
```

Flask

```
@app.route('/predict/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    getData = request.get_data()
    clothes = getData.decode("utf-8")
    recImageList = recommend(clothes)
    return jsonify(imageList=recImageList)
```

Error

[image]

Comment: My guess is that the error isn't with jQuery. Something's not right about the backend.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Not really. 500 errors generally refer to server problems, but there isn't much here to work with.

Comment: What information can i provide?

Comment: Dunno. I'm a front-end developer who was drawn to your jQuery and ajax tags.

Comment: Can you view the server logs? Generally the Python/Flask errors will show there, that might give you a better idea of what's going on.